# Disable content creation outside group context

Tags: 9, group

I'm using the group module.

I have a content type for which nodes should only ever exist as members of groups.

Is there a sensible way to disable creation from `/node/add/{content_type}` so that nodes can only be created from `group/{group}/content/create/group_node:{content_type}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple:
The regular permissions page, `/admin/people/permissions`, controls access to `/node/add/{content_type}`.
The group-level permissions, `admin/group/types/{group_type}/permissions`, controls access to `group/{group}/content/create/group_node:{content_type}`.
If you have the appropriate checkbox(es) unchecked on the former, and checked on the latter, you'll get what you're after.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks! I've been working as admin so that all gets bypassed, but makes sense for regular users.